# How to get the indices of at least two consecutive values that are all greater than a threshold?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, let's consider the following numpy array:

```py
[1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10]
```

Also, let's suppose that the threshold is equal to `3`.
That is to say that we are looking for sequences of **at least two consecutive** values that are all above the threshold.

The output would be the **indices** of those values, which in our case is:

```py
[[3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

If the output array was flattened that would work as well!

```py
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

---

#### Output Explanation

In our initial array we can see that for `index = 1` we have the value `5`, which is greater than the threshold, but is not part of a sequence (of at least two values) where every value is greater than the threshold. That's why this index would **not** make it to our output.

On the other hand, for indices `[3, 4, 5]` we have a sequence of (at least two) neighboring values `[5, 4, 6]` where each and every of them are above the threshold and that's the reason that their indices are included in the final output!

---

#### My Code so far

I have approached the issue with something like this:

```py
(arr > 3).nonzero()
```

The above command gathers the indices of all the items that are above the threshold. However, I cannot determine if they are consecutive or not. I have thought of trying a `diff` on the outcome of the above snippet and then may be locating ones (that is to say that indices are one after the other). Which would give us:

```py
np.diff((arr > 3).nonzero())
```

But I'd still be missing something here.

Comment: Please mention the code you have tried ? and issue you faced with it ?

Comment: I added the code that I've come up with so far :-) @Abhi

Comment: Added solution hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convolve a boolean array with a window full of `1` of size `win_size` (`[1] * win_size`), then you will obtain an array where there is the value `win_size` where the condition held for `win_size` items:

```py
import numpy as np

def groups(arr, *, threshold, win_size, merge_contiguous=False, flat=False):
    conv = np.convolve((arr >= threshold).astype(int), [1] * win_size, mode="valid")
    indexes_start = np.where(conv == win_size)[0]
    indexes = [np.arange(index, index + win_size) for index in indexes_start]
    
    if flat or merge_contiguous:
        indexes = np.unique(indexes)
        if merge_contiguous:
            indexes = np.split(indexes, np.where(np.diff(indexes) != 1)[0] + 1)
    return indexes


arr = np.array([1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10])
threshold = 3
win_size = 2

print(groups(arr, threshold=threshold, win_size=win_size))
print(groups(arr, threshold=threshold, win_size=win_size, merge_contiguous=True))
print(groups(arr, threshold=threshold, win_size=win_size, flat=True))
```

```
[array([3, 4]), array([4, 5]), array([8, 9])]
[array([3, 4, 5]), array([8, 9])]
[3 4 5 8 9]
```

Comment: There was an offset in `if merge_contiguous:`, fixed now.

Comment: What does the * do in the arguments of groups?

Comment: It forces the user to use keywords arguments for following arguments. It is best practice, so you don't mix up `threshold` and `win_size` inadvertently.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using simple numpy operations

```python
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10])

arr_padded = np.concatenate(([0], arr, [0]))
a = np.where(arr_padded > 3, 1, 0)

da = np.diff(a)

idx_start = (da == 1).nonzero()[0]
idx_stop = (da == -1).nonzero()[0]

valid = (idx_stop - idx_start >= 2).nonzero()[0]

result = [list(range(idx_start[i], idx_stop[i])) for i in valid]
print(result)
```

**Explanation**

Array `a` is a padded binary version of the original array, with `1`s where the original elements are greater than three. `da` contains `1`s where "islands" of 1s begin in `a`, and `-1` where the "islands" end in `a`. Due to the padding, there is guaranteed to be an equal number of `1`s and `-1`s in `da`. Extracting their indices, we can calculate the length of the islands. Valid index pairs are those whose respective "islands" have length >= 2. Then, its just a matter of generating all numbers between the index bounds of the valid "islands".

Answer (score 1):

I follow your original idea. You are almost done.

I use another `diff2` to pick the index of the first value in a sequence. See comments in code for details.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([ 1,  5,  0,  5,  4,  6,  1, -1,  5, 10])
threshold = 3

all_idx = (arr > threshold).nonzero()[0]
# array([1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])

result = np.empty(0)
if all_idx.size > 1:
    diff1 = np.zeros_like(all_idx)
    diff1[1:] = np.diff(all_idx)
    # array([0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1])
    diff1[0] = diff1[1]
    # array([2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1])
    # **Positions with a value 1 in diff1 should be reserved.**

    # But we also want the position before each 1. Create another diff2
    diff2 = np.zeros_like(all_idx)
    diff2[:-1] = np.diff(diff1)
    # array([ 2, -1,  0,  2, -2,  0])
    # **Positions with a negative value in diff2 should be reserved.**

    result = all_idx[(diff1==1) | (diff2<0)]

print(result)
# array([3, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try something different using window views, I'm not sure this works all the time so counterexamples are welcome. It has the advantage of not requiring Python loops.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as window


def consec_thresh(arr, thresh):
    win = window(np.argwhere(arr > thresh), (2, 1))
    return np.unique(win[np.diff(win, axis=2).ravel() == 1, :,:].ravel())
```

#### How does it work?

So we start with the array and gather the indices where the threshold is met:

```
In [180]: np.argwhere(arr > 3)
Out[180]:
array([[1],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Then we build a sliding window that makes up pair of values along the column (which is the reason for the `(2, 1)` shape of the window).

```
In [181]: window(np.argwhere(arr > 3), (2, 1))
Out[181]:
array([[[[1],
         [3]]],


       [[[3],
         [4]]],


       [[[4],
         [5]]],


       [[[5],
         [8]]],


       [[[8],
         [9]]]])
```

Now we want to take the difference inside each pair, if it's one then the indices are consecutive.

```
In [182]: np.diff(window(np.argwhere(arr > 3), (2, 1)), axis=2)
Out[182]:
array([[[[2]]],


       [[[1]]],


       [[[1]]],


       [[[3]]],


       [[[1]]]])
```

We can plug those values back in the windows we created above,

```
In [185]: window(np.argwhere(arr > 3), (2, 1))[np.diff(window(np.argwhere(arr > 3), (2, 1)), axis=2).ravel() == 1, :, :]
Out[185]:
array([[[[3],
         [4]]],


       [[[4],
         [5]]],


       [[[8],
         [9]]]])
```

Then we can ravel (flatten without copy when possible), we have to get rid of the repeated indices created by windowing so I call `np.unique`. We ravel again and get:

```
 array([3, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Good idea, but you need to make sure that the input shape is not smaller than the window shape, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @ILS I don't think that's too much of a problem, the shape can be passed as an argument instead of being hard-coded and it'll fail early (at the first function line) if the window is somehow too big.

Comment: Yes. I meant `np.argwhere(arr > 3)` may be less than `(2, 1)` to make `window` crash, which depends on `arr`.

Comment: Fair enough, but if it's that small, then OP can do it by hand 

Answer (score 0):

The below iteration code should help with `O(n)` complexity

```py
arr = [1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10]

threshold = 3
sequence = 2

output = []
temp_arr = []        

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] > threshold:
        temp_arr.append(i)
    else:
        if len(temp_arr) >= sequence:
            output.append(temp_arr)
        temp_arr = []
if len(temp_arr):
    output.append(temp_arr)
    temp_arr = []
    
print(output)

# Output
# [[3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a for loop with two indces. You will have one that starts at j=1 and the other at i=0, both stepping forward by 1.
You can then ask if the value at both is greater than the threshold, if so
add the indices to a list and keep moving forward with j until the threshold or .next() is not greater than threshhold.

```
values = [1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10]
res=[]
threshold= 3

i=0
j=0
for _ in values:
  j=i+1
  lista=[]
  try:
      print(f"i: {i} j:{j}")
      # check if condition is met
      if(values[i] > threshold and values[j] > threshold):
        lista.append(i)
        # add sequence 
        while values[j] > threshold:
          lista.append(j)
          print(f"j while: {j}")
          j+=1
          if(j>=len(values)):
            break
        res.append(lista)
        
      i=j
      if(j>=len(values)): 
        break
  except:
    print("ex")
```

this works. but needs refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following code:

```py
# Simple is better than complex
# Complex is better than complicated

arr = [1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 6, 1, -1, 5, 10]

arr_3=[i if arr[i]>3 else 'a' for i in range(len(arr))]

arr_4=''.join(str(x) for x in arr_3)

i=0

while i<len(arr_5):
    if len(arr_5[i]) <=1:
        del arr_5[i]
    else:
        i+=1
        
arr_6=[list(map(lambda x: int(x), list(x))) for x in arr_5]

print(arr_6)
```

**Outputs:**

```py
[[3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that makes use of pandas `Series`:

```py
thresh = 3
win_size = 2

s = pd.Series(arr)

# locating groups of values where there are at least (win_size) consecutive values above the threshold
groups = s.groupby(s.le(thresh).cumsum().loc[s.gt(thresh)]).transform('count').ge(win_size)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

We can now easily take their indices in a 1D array:

```py
np.flatnonzero(groups)

# array([3, 4, 5, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
```

OR multiple lists:

```py
[np.arange(index.start, index.stop) for index in np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_not_equal(groups.values, value=True))]

# [array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([8, 9], dtype=int64)]
```